# Access environment-specific settings class inside factory method

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, configuration, microsoft.extensions.configuration

My project is a Windows background service with .NET 8.

I want to use Microsoft Entity Framework Core in my current project. I also want to use the `DbContextFactory` to create an instance where needed.

Therefore I need to set this up in my `Program.cs` file.

Actually I need to explain a little bit more my current setup of my project. In `appsettings.json` there is a property value, which controls which database should be used.

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
...
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "DaysBetweenExecution": 1,
    "ExecutionHour": 3,
    "ExecutionMinute": 0,
    "Environment": "Dev"
},
...
```

As you can see here, the Environment is set to `Dev`.

So I setup this `AppSettings` in my `Program.cs` like this:

```
...
builder.Services.AddOptions<AppSettings>()
                .BindConfiguration("AppSettings");
...
```

to use these settings in my application.

The `AppSettings` class looks like this:

```
namespace BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.AppSettings
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public int DaysBetweenExecution { get; set; } = -1; 
        public int ExecutionHour { get; set; } = -1;
        public int ExecutionMinute { get; set; } = -1;
        public string Environment { get; set; } = "Dev";
    }
}
```

This value `Dev` is being handled by the class `Environment`.

This is the `Environment` class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.Enviroment
{
    public class Environment : IEnvironment
    {
        private IOptions<AppSettings.AppSettings> _AppSettings;

        public Enums.Environment Current { get; set; }

        public Environment(IOptions<AppSettings.AppSettings> appSettings) { 
            _AppSettings = appSettings;
            Current = GetEnvironmentFromAppSettings();
        }

        public Enums.Environment GetEnvironmentFromAppSettings()
        {
            switch(_AppSettings.Value.Environment.ToLower())
            {
                case "dev":
                    return Enums.Environment.Dev;

                case "test":
                    return Enums.Environment.Test;

                case "ittest":
                case "it-test":
                    return Enums.Environment.ITTest;

                case "live":
                case "production":
                    return Enums.Environment.Live;

                default:
                    return Enums.Environment.Dev;
            }
        }

        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            switch (_Environment.Current)
            {
                case Enums.Environment.Live:
                    return "connection string";

                case Enums.Environment.Test:
                    return "connection string test";

                case Enums.Environment.ITTest:
                    return "connection string it test";

                case Enums.Environment.Dev:
                    return "connection string dev";

                default:
                    return "connection string dev";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `AppSettings` are injected in the constructor. This class provides me the correct connection string based on the `Environment` setting in `appsettings.json`.

Now my issue: I need to setup the factory for Entity Framework Core in `Program.cs`.

I want to do it like this :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<IMP_GG_Context>(options =>
{
    var environment = new BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.Enviroment.Environment();
    options.UseSqlServer(environment.GetConnectionString());

}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

The issue here is, that this line is not working:

```
var environment = new BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.Enviroment.Environment();
```

...because `Environment` needs the `AppSettings` or better `IOptions<AppSettings.AppSettings>` in the constructor. How can I manage that in `Program.cs`?

Or are there better ways to do this?

Maybe, if it helps. Here is my full current code of `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;
using BrochureCreationService.GUI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "Brochure Creation Service";
});

LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<EventLogSettings, EventLogLoggerProvider>(builder.Services);
builder.Services.AddOptions<AppSettings>().BindConfiguration("AppSettings");
builder.Services.AddOptions<WordSettings>().BindConfiguration("WordSettings");
builder.Services.AddOptions<PdfSettings>().BindConfiguration("PdfSettings");
builder.Services.AddOptions<EmailSettings>().BindConfiguration("EmailSettings");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEnvironment, BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.Enviroment.Environment>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceController, ServiceController>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IExecution, Execution>();
//... some more dependencies with AddTransient

builder.Services.AddScoped<IIMP_GG_Context, IMP_GG_Context>();

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<IMP_GG_Context>(options =>
{
    var appSettingsOptions = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
    var environment = new BrochureCreationService.ApplicationLogic.Models.Enviroment.Environment(appSettingsOptions);
    options.UseSqlServer(environment.GetConnectionString());

}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
IHost host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to be a summary of your question, and not simply a collection of technologies you are using. Refer to [ask] for more information.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can have environment-specific appconfigs ...

Comment: The question is unclear. There's no AppSettings class in .NET Core. The configuration middleware creates (and injects) an `IConfiguration` class that has a [GetConnectionStrings(name) extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). That's available through `builder.Configuration`

Comment: Both the generic and web host [support environment-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder#host-builder-settings) out of the box. That's how `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` are used. You can easily add environmet-specific settings by eg checking the OS and calling `AddJson("appsettings.{OS}.json")` - that's how I handled settings when I worked on a Mac but had to deploy to Windows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess the `AppSettings` class is custom and only a name-clash with "appsettings.json"

Comment: I've added the `AppSettings` class to my post and yes, it is custom!

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The question is specific. There is only one question in it: "...because Environment needs the AppSettings or better IOptions<AppSettings.AppSettings> in the constructor. How can I manage that in Program.cs?"

Comment: @dns_nx remove the custom classes and use Configuration in the way it's designed. It's unclear why you don't do that.

Comment: And environment-specific settings are *already* used in your code, because, as the link I posted earlier shows, environment-specific appsettings.json files are loaded by default, right after `appsettings.json` and before secrets, environment variables and command line arguments. That means the environment-specific files override `appsettings.json` already, and can be overriden by env variables and CLI arguments

Comment: @Fildor AppSettings is also the name of the ASP.NET 1.0 weakly typed settings class that's available through the `ConfigurationManager` compatibility package in ASP.NET Core. Many people migrating from WebForms to ASP.NET Core use it during the transition

Comment: @dns_nx The TITLE is anything but specific: _"C# - Microsoft Entity Framework Core factory - dependency injection"_ - that's just a list of stuff you're working with. [ask] explicitly states: _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem?"_ - can you say that your title satisfies that brief? As a user with as much rep as you have, you should know how to write a title by now, IMHO.

Comment: Even with a single settings file, it's a *lot* easier to use the environment as a root for setting instead of a property. The entire `Environment` class can be replaced with `.BindConfiguration($"{environment}:AppSettings");`. It's more secure and easier to use separate files though with just the overridden settings. There's no reason to include Development settings in a production deploymrnt after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another overload for `AddDbContextFactory` which you can inject `IServiceProvider`, so easily it's possible to get the `IEnvironment` service from DI:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    var environment = provider.GetRequiredService<IEnvironment>();
    
    options.UseSqlServer(environment.GetConnectionString());
}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I highly recommend you to use an app secret. It's not safe to keep your `ConnectionString`s in your source control.

Read following article for using this feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets

So for your DI issue you can simply add following codes:

```
var options = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
```

and you can create a new instance of `Environment` using this options.

Comment: Thnaks for your comment. It underlines me `Configuration`. It provides me 2 solutions: The first is using `System.Configration` and the 2nd is to use `Microsoft.Extension.Configuration`. Both give me the error that the function `GetSection` is missing. Any idea?

Comment: And as you can see in the class constructor of `Environment` I don't need a instance of `AppSettings` but of `IOptions<AppSettings>`!

Comment: and just one more comment. The connection strings are kept encrypted. But to keep it simple, I just added the (fake) connection strings as plain text.

Comment: @dns_nx what you ask is basic usage of the configuration middleware. You need to know how to read config settings *before* you try more advanced scenarios like Options. `builder.Configuration` gives you the IConfiguration object you need to retrieve connection strings or raw values